How can I read object ID from the request API from Parse Cloud triggers
I have a class of Doctor and by default if I can read data of specific doctor all what I have to is to send GET request to
www.example.com/classes/Doctor/<objectId>

I am using Parse Cloud function of beforeFind and I want to read that , how can I do it
Parse.Cloud.beforeFind('Doctor', async (request) => {
  // I want to read <objectId> here
})

I tried different methods like:

const objectId = request.query.get("objectId");
const objectId = request.query.id;
const objectId = request.query.objectId;

and none of them worked
Just want to know the right method so I can read the 

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python?Rest?C#? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.
